# Ionic 2 get RESTful API issue

Tags: rest, api, ionic2

I am getting a RESTful API, and I have some question about the getting JSON, here is the JSON I get:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "user": {
        "loggedIn": true,
        "name": "Nulra",
        "password": ""
    }
}
```

And the part for getting the JSON in auth-service.ts:

```
login(credentials) {

    if(this.data){
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    let opt: RequestOptions;
    let myHeaders: Headers = new Headers;

    myHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    myHeaders.append('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    opt = new RequestOptions({
        headers: myHeaders
    })

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get(apiUrl+'login/0/login?email='+credentials.email+'&password='+credentials.password, opt)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
```

And in my login.ts:

```
doLogin() {
    this.authService.login(this.loginData).then(data => {
        console.log("NULRA CHECKING: ",data);
    }, (err) => {

    });
}
```

I discover it just getting the user part in JSON, and missing the result part in JSON when I inspect in the console log. How can I get the both result and user part?

the console log:

```
Object {loggedIn: true, name: "Nulra", password: ""}
```

Comment: Can you post your console output of `console.log("NULRA CHECKING: ",data);`?

Comment: Hi, hrdkisback, i have added the console log print.Thanks

Comment: I find it may be cache problem, please i get other json with same domain, it give me a same object, anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for get `json` object from `REST-API` please check

`console.log("NULRA CHECKING: " + JSON.stringify(data));` output in console.

**login.ts:**

```
doLogin() {
    this.authService.login(this.loginData).subscribe( (data) => {
        console.log("NULRA CHECKING: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("Error : " + error);
    });
}
```

**auth-service.ts:**

```
login(credentials): Observable<any> {

    let opt: RequestOptions;
    let myHeaders: Headers = new Headers;

    myHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    myHeaders.append('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    opt = new RequestOptions({
        headers: myHeaders
    })

    return this.http.get(apiUrl + 'login/0/login?email=' + credentials.email + '&password=' + credentials.password, opt)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Thanks hrdkisback, turns out I discover is the server problem not the app code problem. After upgrade the server, some behaviour have changed, now i fixed the server, it can return json i want not only the model object. Anyway thanks again=).